# single threaded script is consuming too much cpu on a multi core processor

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu-usage

I have written a code to help accumulate some data over a constant time interval from a non-constant data set. It is working as expected on my current computer which is a 6 core processor (Intel i5-8400), and consumes ~25% of CPU usage. The problem is that now I am trying to rerun the same code on another computer which has 40 cores (Intel Xeon E5-2630 v4), and as soon as it starts the below function, it spikes to 55% CPU usage, while I was expecting it to be closer to 5%.

This has become an issue because I am sharing this computer with other people and it is hindering their work. Doing a comparison of the time it takes to run the script between the two computers, it seems to be negligible so I am not sure if it is actually using all of the processors (which makes sense, since I have no idea of how to multi thread loops!)

I have previously tried to find an answer, and the closest answer I could find was that it may be due to a while loop ([Python script too much cpu usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972324/python-script-too-much-cpu-usage)) but I don't think that is applicable to my case... Most other questions were related to how to increase cpu usage, which is the opposite of my problem.

```
def accumulate_value (table_data_1,i_time_step):

    # table_data_1 formatted as a dataframe with columns names ['value','date_time']

    table_data_1.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

    table_data_1["delta_time"] = table_data_1["date_time"].diff(periods=1).dt.seconds/60
    table_data_1["delta_time_aux"] = 0
    table_data_1["value_aux"] = 0
    table_data_1["datetime_stamp"] = pd.to_datetime(0)


    # Start loop

    for aux_counter_1 in table_data_1.index.values.tolist():

        table_data_1_aux1 = table_data_1.loc[aux_counter_1:,:]
        table_data_3 = table_data_1_aux1.loc[table_data_1_aux1.index[table_data_1_aux1.loc[:,'date_time'] - table_data_1_aux1.loc[aux_counter_1,'date_time'] <= datetime.timedelta(minutes=i_time_step)],:]


        if len(table_data_3.index) > 1 :

            table_data_1.iloc[aux_counter_1,3] = datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(table_data_3.iloc[-1,1] - table_data_3.iloc[0,1])/60
            if table_data_1.iloc[aux_counter_1,3] >= i_time_step:
                table_data_1.iloc[aux_counter_1,4] = table_data_3.loc[:,'value'].sum() - table_data_3.iloc[-1,0]
            else:
                table_data_1.iloc[aux_counter_1,4] = table_data_3.loc[:,'value'].sum()
            table_data_1.iloc[aux_counter_1,5] = table_data_3.iloc[-1,1]

        elif len(table_data_3.index) == 1 :
            table_data_1.iloc[aux_counter_1,3] = 0
            table_data_1.iloc[aux_counter_1,4] = table_data_3.loc[:,'value'].sum()
            table_data_1.iloc[aux_counter_1,5] = table_data_3.iloc[-1,1]
        else:
                print(table_data_3)


    table_data_1["year_stamp"] = table_data_1["datetime_stamp"].dt.year

    table_data_2 = table_data_2

    return table_data_2
```

Comment: Is it 55% usage of all cores or just the active core?

Comment: Upon a closer check of task manager, I have noticed that under the Performance tab, it only shows 1 graph (https://imgur.com/a/3tv58at) rather than a graph for each processor. This has confused me a bit!

EDIT: A closer inspection at resource monitor, I am able to clarify, yes, it is the CPU total. It seems to be using all cores except for "Service CPU Usage"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is hat numpy is creating a large number of threads, assuming it is the only process running on the machine.

See [Limit number of threads in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791550/limit-number-of-threads-in-numpy) for how to limit the number of threads used.

Comment: Thanks so much! It fixed my issue. Out of curiosity, do you know why this behaviour occurs? (It was running as expected in my machine)

Comment: Numpy uses multiple threads internally to run as fast as possible. I think the assumption (by default) is that there aren't other users, so it should use as much CPU as is available, or at least a large fraction of what is available.